# why is my perl command line replace not working?

Tags: perl

I'm running this but it doesn't seem to replace anything:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/page?user_id=/page?uid=/g' *
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I want to replace `page?user_id=` with `page?uid=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The '?' is a special character, indicating that the e needs to be matched 0 or once](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers), so it needs to be escaped if you want to search for a '?' instead of an optional 'e'. Escaping with '\':

try

`s/page\?user_id=/page?uid=/g`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Quotemeta:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\Qpage?user_id=\E/page?uid=/g' file
```

As a side note I thought why don't you change only `user_id` to `uid`.